# The regular semisimple element in the algebraic group

Tags: algebraic-groups

Suppose some maximal torus $T$ of $G$ is $C_G(T)$, then the set of semisimple elements for which $C_G(s)$ is a torus contains a nonempty open set. Such element are called regular semisimple.

I want to know how to prove this claim and want to find some good examples for some common algebraic groups such as $\mathrm{SL}(n,K)$.

Comment: If $K$ in the question is algebraically closed then any semisimple element $s$ can be diagonalized; it is regular if and only if all eigenvalues are distinct. This is equivalent, as Turgeon refers to Borel's book, to being outside the kernel of every root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I will assume you are still interested in getting an answer to this problem.)

By Lemma 12.2 of Borel's *Linear Algebraic Groups*, being regular is equivalent to being fixed by no roots. Therefore, the set of regular elements is a finite intersection of open sets, and so it is open.